# In HangFire, can I Enqueue with a queue name instead of using the Queue attribute?

Tags: hangfire

This [documentation](http://hangfire.io/features.html) says that you can specify a queue by using the `Queue` attribute on the method to be invoked.  This assumes that you always want execute a method on the same queue.  Is there a way for the process that calls `Enqueue` to specify the name of the queue to put the job into (effectively putting the decision-making in the hands of the job generator, not the definition of the job).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With a instance of IBackgroundJobClient you can specify a queue.

```
IBackgroundJobClient hangFireClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
EnqueuedState myQueueState = new Hangfire.States.EnqueuedState("myQueue");
hangFireClient.Create<SomeClass>(c => c.SomeMethod(), myQueueState);
```

Note that in this way, a retry will put the job back to the default queue. You will require additional code to retry in the same queue, using a JobFilter

http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/one-queue-for-the-whole-farm-and-one-queue-by-server/490/3

Comment: I've tried that but it gives me "Cannot create an instance of an inteface" despite using the ...Create<IFoo>(x=>x.Bar(), myQueueState). Any idéas?

Comment: Probably missing the Dependency Inject Resolver, but i'm guessing by now you already fix your issue. Sorry, didnt see your question sooner.

Comment: Worked for me. The class and method cannot be static, but it works fine.

Comment: This works. Something to note is, if your method throws an exception while processing, Hangfire will requeue it to a "default" queue (unless you specify a queue through an attribute).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the queue **Dynamically** you can follow this way.

This implementation works for all `Enqueue` , `Schedule` and `ContinueJobWith`

The trick happen on `[Queue("{0}")]`. Hangfire will pass job arguments to the given pattern (`"{0}"`) using `String.Format("{0}", job.Args)` to get the actual queue on **every state change**, so the target queue will be applied **even for retries**.

**Highlighted Code Syntax :**

```c#
// Enqueue "MyBackgroundJob1" under "critical" queue
var job2 = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyBackgroundJob1("critical", 523));

// Use one of following Attributes depending on your hangfire version
//[AdvancedQueue("{0}")] //  1.6.X 
[Queue("{0}")] // In 1.7.X
public void MyBackgroundJob1(string queueName, int arg)
{
    // Job implementation
}
```

---

**Full Implementation :**

```c#
public class HangfireDynamicQueue
{
    public void EnqueJobs()
    {
        // Enqueue "MyBackgroundJob1" under "default" queue
        var job1 = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyBackgroundJob1("default", 123));

        // Enqueue "MyBackgroundJob1" under "critical" queue
        var job2 = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyBackgroundJob1("critical", 523));

        // Execute "MyBackgroundJob1" after 10 seconds under "delayed" queue
        var job3 = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => MyBackgroundJob1("delayed", 678), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        // Run "MyBackgroundJob2" after job3 under "delayed" queue
        var job4 = BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith(job3, () => MyBackgroundJob2("delayed", 435));
    }

    // Use one of following Attributes depending on your hangfire version
    //[AdvancedQueue("{0}")] //  1.6.X 
    [Queue("{0}")] // In 1.7.X
    public void MyBackgroundJob1(string queueName, int arg)
    {
        // Job implementation
    }

    // Use one of following Attributes depending on your hangfire version
    //[AdvancedQueue("{0}")] //  1.6.X 
    [Queue("{0}")] // In 1.7.X
    public void MyBackgroundJob2(string queueName, int arg)
    {
        // Job implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an underrated hack. I'm disappointed in the hangfire team for not implementing this on "BackgroundJobClient" level at least.

Answer (score 2):

Since adding an extra parameter seems to be so hard for the Hangfire team ;-)....

...I've found the most convenient way is to make two methods that just call the actual implementation, and put different `[Queue]` attributes on each.

Usually if I need to switch queues it's between dev / production and I want to just call something like `RunOrder(...)` with `isTestOrder=boolean` and not be concerned about queues at that level.

```
public void RunOrder(int orderId, bool isTestOrder) 
{
   if (isTestOrder) 
   {
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _RunTestOrder(orderId));
   } 
   else 
   {
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _RunOrder(orderId));
   }
}

[Queue("dev")]
public void _RunTestOrder(int orderId) {
  OrderProcessor.RunOrder(orderId); // actual code to call processor
}

[Queue("production")]`
public void _RunProductionOrder(int orderId) {
  OrderProcessor.RunOrder(orderId); // is the same in both 'hangfire proxies'
}
```

Note usage of `_` to indicate these aren't meant to be called directly. I don't remember off hand if hangfire methods need to be public or not - but if they do need to be then the `_` is more important.